# Dynamically configuring remote web service endpoint in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to call a remote SOAP/CXF web service from a Spring app. The complication is I cannot pre-configure invocation params (remote endpoint URL) at app startup via XML or Java config. Instead I need to obtain them dynamically from an external configuration, taking a fresh value each invocation. (Actually the config is backed by LDAP and accessbible via a custom Java library.)

¿Does Spring 4 offers a common way to achieve that?

For now, I came with the following custom solution, but I don't like it much beacause I need to define a dummy proxy class `DynamicallyConfiguredMyService` at least.

```
@Component
class ParentBean {
    @Inject
    MyService service;
    ...
    service.doAction(); // calling WS
}

interface MyService {
    void doAction();
}

@Component
class DynamicallyConfiguredMyService implements MyService {
    void doAction() {
        getRealService.doAction();
    }

    private MyService getRealService() {
        String url = get URL from external config
        MyService endpoint = new MyServiceHelper().getMyService();
        Map<String, Object> ctx = ((BindingProvider) endpoint).getRequestContext();
        ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, url);
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

Spring 4, Java 7, JBoss EAP 6.4.x